# Out of Range Exception - Substring - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of phone numbers some with extensions, some with out.
I regex my phone number to return just the digits.

I then create a string for the first 10 digits(area code + number).

I compare this strings length and compare it to the original.
If there is a difference, I use the remainder as the extension.

In the code below, I keep getting an out of range exception. I've debugged it, and it does not appear to be out of range. Anyone see what I'm missing?

```
var prePhone = emp.y.PhoneNumber;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prePhone))
{
    string xPhone = Regex.Replace(prePhone, "[^0-9]", "");
    string number = xPhone.Substring(0, 10);
    int extMath = xPhone.Length - number.Length;

    if (extMath >= 1)
    {   int preExt = 9 + extMath;
        string ext = xPhone.Substring(10, preExt);//Out of range exception
        em.Phone = beautifyPhoneNumber(number, ext);
    }
    else {
        string ext = null;
        em.Phone = beautifyPhoneNumber(number, ext);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not appear to be out of range".
Can you please post the exact string that is causing the exception?

Comment: @dariogriffo it's noted with the comment in the code.

Comment: Please can you tell us what the stack trace is for the error, indicating which line in your source is the issue

Comment: What we are curious about is what values xPhone and preExt have when the Exception happens.

Comment: preExt = "12" exPhone = "7195535223212" at time of exception

Comment: Shouldn't it be `xPhone.Substring(10, extMath)`? Seeing you as you add 9 to your preExt, you'll get a Substring of (10, 11)?

Comment: Well, there we have it @Mark: The string is simply too short. You can't get it's position from index 10 to index 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string ext = xPhone.Substring(10, preExt)
```

The second argument is not the ending index, it is the length of the string you want to extract.

Since preExt > 10 in your code, xPhone must be more than 20 characters in length, (since you're starting at index 10), otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: More info for OP here: [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)